# Rhino.Security and IEntityInformationExtractor

Tags: structuremap, rhino, ninject-2, rhino-security

I've recently downloaded Rhino.Security and I am trying to implement permissions on a entity.
Since I like Ninject (v2) I would like to put together a simple example to start with.
In my NinjectModule I've bound the repository and the services:

```
Bind<ISessionFactory>()
    .ToProvider(new SessionFactoryProvider())
    .InSingletonScope();
Bind<ISession>().ToProvider(new SessionProvider())
    .InSingletonScope();
Bind<IAuthorizationRepository>()
     .To<AuthorizationRepository>()
     .InSingletonScope();
Bind<IPermissionsService>()
    .To<PermissionsService>()
    .InSingletonScope();
Bind<IAuthorizationService>()
    .To<AuthorizationService>()
    .InSingletonScope();
Bind<IPermissionsBuilderService>()
    .To<PermissionsBuilderService>()
    .InSingletonScope();
```

I am testing everything in a console app and everything works fine.
I can run this test with no problem:

```
public void RunTest()
{
Model.User user1;
Rhino.Security.Model.UsersGroup grp1;

    using (session)
    {
        session.BeginTransaction();

        user1 = new Model.User { Name = "xxx xxx" };
        session.Save(user1);
        session.Flush();

        grp1 = authorizationRepository.CreateUsersGroup("Administrators");
        session.Flush();

        authorizationRepository.AssociateUserWith(user1, grp1);
        session.Flush();

        var OpAccountEdit = authorizationRepository.CreateOperation("/Account/Edit");
        session.Flush();

        permissionsBuilderService
        .Allow(OpAccountEdit)
        .For(grp1)
        .OnEverything()
        .Level(10)
        .Save();

        permissionsBuilderService
        .Deny(OpAccountEdit)
        .For(user1)
        .OnEverything()
        .Level(10)
        .Save();

        Console.WriteLine(authorizationService.IsAllowed(user1, "/Account/Edit"));

        session.Transaction.Rollback();

        Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }
```

Now, I would like to define a permission for an account; something like this:

```
account1 = new Model.Account() { Name = "My Account", SecurityKey = new Guid(), Id = 1 };
session.Save(account1);
session.Flush();

permissionsBuilderService
   .Allow("/Account/Delete")
   .For(user1)
   .On(account1)
   .Level(20)
   .Save();
```

I've defined my class, as Ayende did in the sample code found in the solution:

```
public class AccountInfromationExtractor : IEntityInformationExtractor<Model.Account>
{
...
}
```

and I've tried to bind (in my ninject module) the interface IEntityInformationExtractor to the class

```
 Bind<IEntityInformationExtractor<Model.Account>>()
   .To<AccountInfromationExtractor>();
```

but when I run my app I get an "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**." in the Security class.
The service locator cannot resolve the instance and it generates and exception right here:

```
var extractor = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEntityInformationExtractor<TEntity>>();
```

Is there anyone who tried to use Ninject with Rhino.Security and would be able to help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I couldn't manage to make it work with Ninject so I switched to StructureMap.
Rhino.Security works with MS ServiceLocator to resolve IEntityInformationExtractor.
I've found a ServiceLocator adapter for [StructureMap](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StructureMap%20Adapter)

So I've referenced in my project the following assemblies:

Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
StructureMap
StructureMapAdapter

changed my code to use StructureMap:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddRegistry<StructureMapRegistry>();
            });
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new StructureMapServiceLocator(ObjectFactory.Container));
        }
    }
```

and my StructureMapRegistry class:

```
public class StructureMapRegistry : Registry
{
    public StructureMapRegistry()
    {
        string ConnDb = "Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=RhinoSecurity_Test; Trusted_Connection=true;";

        For<ISessionFactory>()
            .Singleton()
            .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(() => new NHSessionFactory(ConnDb, false).SessionFactory);
        For<ISession>()
            .Singleton()
            .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(x => x.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());
        For<IAuthorizationRepository>()
             .Use<AuthorizationRepository>();
        For<IPermissionsService>()
            .Use<PermissionsService>();
        For<IAuthorizationService>()
            .Use<AuthorizationService>();
        For<IPermissionsBuilderService>()
            .Use<PermissionsBuilderService>();
        For<IEntityInformationExtractor<Model.Account>>()
            .Use(p =>
                {
                return (new AccountInfromationExtractor(p.GetInstance<ISession>()));
                });
    }
}
```

I hope this might help someone.